# Spring Boot - Create custom event loop

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, event-loop

I'm working on a large Spring Boot service with around 60k lines of code. It's calling around 10 dependencies for each incoming request to its single endpoint. There are circuit breakers, timeouts and metrics in place.

The service is not great at managing struggling dependencies. As soon as their responses take longer, the service needs more CPU and its latency goes up. This is bad because we have a latency SLO.

We have made experiments with WebFlux and the prototype looks very promising. Now we want to migrate.

One way to tackle this big project is by migrating dependencies one after the other. We could rewrite them as `Mono<>` and then call them using `block()`. The project can be deployed again immediately. After all dependencies are migrated like this, switch the engine from MVC to WebFlux, then rewrite the `RestController` and all code in between. This would work, but ideally we would like to immediately see performance benefits after migrating the first dependency.

Would it be possible to instead add a WebFlux event loop to the project, run it in a separate thread and migrate dependencies one by one into it? How would that look like? Currently we call dependencies with `@Async` and with a custom thread-pool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event loop is not something you start up by yourself, or write yourself. In webflux the event loop is created by the underlying webserver (netty) that runs a couple of event loops depending on how many cores the host has.

I can't see any way of running 2 different webserver implementations underneath at the same time on a single application. Im not sure and someone from the spring team needs to answer the more specifics here.

Tbh, if this is a big and important project, i'd keep the original server, and then by using a load balancer infront, start out by duplicating the requests and send them to both services and implement an endpoint, run it in parallell for a while to se that it works good, and then switch off the parallell running. And do this for each/a couple of endpoint at the time.

There are also specific shadowing tools for this purpose like [`goreplay`](https://github.com/buger/goreplay).

```
req ---------> LB ------> original
                \
                 \------> webflux


req ---------> LB
                \
                 \------> webflux


// Or for instance goreplay that runs on a host and also 
// shadows requests forward to another service
req ---------> original
                   \
                    \------> webflux
```

There is never any smooth way of migrating something, ever.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise that the event loop is handled natively by netty. In that case we will probably replace the dependencies one-by-one and call them using `block()` until we switch the engine.

Comment: if i remember correctly you can actually return a `Mono` straight out of controllers in a non-webflux application and the framework will handle the blocking for you.